# “Preview” app crashing Mac OS X 10.10.5 (Yosemite)

Tags: macos, crash, osx-yosemite, preview.app

So my preview is crashing, I have a [crash report here](http://pastebin.com/k3GBV9CM).

I’ve tried a few things:

1. Deleting all Preview preferences
2. *Completely* reinstalling Preview from Pacifist

Every time I open up **anything** in “Preview” it crashes.

I’m not sure what the cause of this is, nothing described seems to fix this, I've tried:

- [Preview.app always crashes.](https://superuser.com/questions/835035/preview-app-always-crashes)
- [Simple fix for the Preview and TextEdit Crash after Lion OS X Update.](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3197855?start=30&tstart=0)
- [Preview Crashes Repeatedly on Yosemite 10.10.1.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157888/preview-crashes-repeatedly-on-yosemite-10-10-1)

If you would like more information or would like me to clarify, please let me know.

Comment: When is it crashing?

Comment: @Tetsujin anytime any file is opened whether it be an image or pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same situation as you. -- Not only did Preview crash every time I opened a file, the *Application Specific Information* section of the Crash Reports was identical to yours. I tried all the steps suggested by Tetsujin, but had no success. Hours looking at other sites produced suggestions related to fixing permissions and deleting items in ~/Library/, but all failed.

*Then I found a posting that fixed the crash problem!* It suggested:

- **Reinstall any recently deleted font**

For this person, it was to reinstall Office 2011 fonts. Because I had recently upgraded from MS Office 2011 to Office 2016, reinstalling Office 2011 fonts was my fix as well. Clearly, the upgrade process had deleted a key font.

If you have recently made any changes to an MS Office Installation or deleted *any* fonts, try reinstalling the affected fonts next.

Comment: I had removed a bunch of fonts that were causing Photoshop to crash. Restoring those fixed the Preview crashes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is also a preference file and data in your `~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/` folder, that you could move somewhere temporarily to see if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Things to try...

- Clear Preview's saved state...
  `~/Library/Saved Application State/com.apple.Preview.savedState` Delete the entire `com.apple.Preview.savedState` folder.
- Fix permissions, Verify & if necessary Repair disk, using Disk Utility.
- Reset Home folder permissions & ACLs using [OnyX](http://www.titanium.free.fr/onyx.html)  - Maintenance tab/permissions, tick the box at the top then Execute.
- Re-apply 10.10.5 using the [10.10.5 combo update](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1832), not the delta from App Store.

Comment: Nothing seemed to work. I'll try reapplying the OS X update

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue! Sometimes simplicity does the trick- my error seemed to be related to markups and highlights I was adding to a PDF, at least based on my analysis of the crash report Preview gave me.

#### Solution

Create a duplicate of the file, and just continue working on that (no loss of work or progress!). You should be all set!