# macOS Preview application: Text boxes cannot be resized vertically, can this be remedied?

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan, preview, annotations

macOS version: El Capitan Version 10.11.6 (15G31)

Preview version: 8.1 (Version 877.7)

When I write a text box annotation, I can tell that text is going into the box when I write it, but the text box is not being resized. It is only a few pixels tall and there are no vertical resize indicators, only horizontal ones (hence I can tell that text makes it into the annotation because I can see the top of the letters in the first line of the text, but nothing else). No matter what font size I select, the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to similar advice in [Preview.app always crashes](https://superuser.com/questions/835035/preview-app-always-crashes) , I was able to get the text boxes to automatically resize themselves again by removing the application data for Preview that was local to my user:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.Preview/
```